# Cannot start Permalink with "about"

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I have a very strange issue. I'm trying to create a page called "About Us" and the permalink renames itself to "us" or if I just try and change it to "about," it reverts to the draft ID. Here's the TS I've done.

- Cleared the trash from pages and posts
- Removed all drafts and revisions
- Reset Permalinks
- Deactivated all plugins
- Activated to Twenty Fourteen
- Searched the database for the word "about" and returned 0 results

I'm very experienced with WP and have tried variations of /%postname%, /%category%/%postname%, etc. If you read the list of t/s that I've already done, you'll see that I have already cleared the trash and pages.

I'm not able to use the word "about" to start ANY permalink. It can even be "About Botswana" and it will revert the permalink to "Botswana." I can't use that word whatsoever to **start** any permalink. Now, if I did "Botswana About" then it creates "botswana-about" with no issue.

Comment: Probably related to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/About_URI_scheme

Comment: I don't think so, I have a page on my WordPress site called [about-me](http://justin.ag/about-me/) that works fine.

Comment: Seems to be a htaccess issue.

Comment: @paul.abbott.wa.us highly doubt it is related to the about URI scheme.  He is stating that the slug of a post cannot begin with about, which would be http://www.example.com/about-us, not about:something.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce, but this is what I'd recommend. Grab the page ID and find it within the wp_posts database table, then manually set the slug to `about` (the `post_name` column.) Sometimes it takes WordPress reading a database change to get it back in the proper process.

If that doesn't work, try to reinstall the latest version of WordPress.